# How do I specify TLS certificate in PyCharm?

Tags: configuration, pycharm

I was using PyCharm for a pretty long time. Some day, I installed PostgreSQL. After some time, I deleted (not uninstalled) the PostgreSQL folder. It has a sad consequence - now when I am trying to install any package, I am getting an error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt.

When I copied google.com certificate to this directory (which I created after the re-installation), it doesn't work. I can imagine that I have to change some variables somewhere after the reinstallation of pycharm. My question is - where should I do it?
Thank you in advance,
Piotr Szkudlarek